# how can I calculate the percentage of 2 values an user entered using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to do a little program, I have to calculate the percentage of savings a user has using the information the user provides. So this is my code

```
savings_box = tk.Entry(new_goal_window, width=75)
savings_box.place(x=450,y=150)

goal_total = tk.Entry(new_goal_window, width=75)
goal_total.place(x=450,y=350)
```

What I need to do is, with the data the user entries, I have to calculate the percentage, however I am not able to convert the entries to a numeric value, I can only have strings instead of integers or floats, and I cannot do a thing with that, what should I do?

Comment: There are `int()` and `float()` functions on converting string to integer and float respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the values from strings to floats:

`percentage = (float(savings_box.get()) / float(goal_total.get())) * 100`